# Variable won't equal string in Azure DevOps YAML if statement

Tags: if-statement, azure-devops, yaml

Got a problem going on.

Given:

```
variables: 
  binType: 'zip'
  zip: 'zip'
```

The following fails:

```
- ${{ if eq(variables['binType'], 'zip') }}:
  - script: 'echo string test worked'
```

And the following works:

```
- ${{ if eq(variables['binType'], variables['zip']) }}:
  - script: 'echo var test worked'
```

Comment: Hi @Josh Coffin. I have tested the sample and it could work fine. You could refer to the answer and check if it could work. If it still get the same issue, you could edit your question and share the error message. If you can't run the pipeline, this could be format issue. You may share your full sample.

Comment: Well, after banging my head against the wall for a long time, it turns out that variables won't resolve in if statements if you're pulling from another template. Parameters, yes. Variables, no. At least, in no form that I can find. The latter example worked because both values turned out to be null.

Comment: Hi @Josh Coffin. Please refer to my update. The variable in template could be passed successfully. If you still have the same issue, you could share your full sample with us.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the variable in Azure Devops Yaml is **String type**. So your if expression should work fine.

I have tested the same Yaml sample:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables: 
  binType: 'zip'


steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables['binType'], 'zip') }}:
  - script: 'echo string test worked'
```

And it could work fine.

[image]

You can try to copy my sample and check if it works.

**Update:**

If you are using the template to pass the variable, you need to reference the template.

Here is an example:

var.yml:

```
variables: 
  binType: 'zip'
  zip: 'zip'
```

azure-pipelines.yml:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:   
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- template: var.yml  

steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables['binType'], 'zip') }}:
  - script: 'echo string test worked'
```

For more detailed info, you could refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse)

Comment: what about a variable that is written to output in a task and you want to check this variable against a condition in the next task (same stage, same job?) @Kevin Lu-MSFT. The documentation doesn't mention this afaik

Comment: nvm, found it trough trial and error. Should be `eq(variables['taskName.binType'], 'zip')`